# Prevent user from creating an event unless a certain word is in the title full calendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I wanted to allow the user to only create events if they include a certain variety of words, e.g the selection of available words would be Sarah, Kate, and Helen, and if the user typed in Joe then an error would appear.

Ideally my goal is to have a dropdown menu that a user selects a title from, but I don't think you can add dropdowns to a full calendar.

Comment: "I don't think you can add dropdowns to a full calendar." ...why not? Apart from dragging to select, there is no functionality in fullCalendar at all for adding events. Anything above and beyond that is already a customisation. How are you getting the user to type this name in at the moment? I guess you used a textbox or a prompt? Just replace that input with a dropdown list instead.

Comment: Maybe a little modal popup with a form would make sense. Pretty sure if you [search](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&rlz=1C1GCEU_enGB821GB821&ei=PiyCXJCVFeKY1fAP4r6byAQ&q=fullcalendar+add+events+modal&oq=fullcalendar+add+events+modal&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30.10910.11254..11423...0.0..0.81.386.5......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.uW3LxelG33w) you could find some existing examples to work from.